# How do I SelectKBest using mutual information from a mixture of discrete and continuous features?

Tags: scikit-learn, feature-selection

I am using scikit learn to train a classification model. I have both discrete and continuous features in my training data. I want to do feature selection using maximum mutual information. If I have vectors `x` and labels `y` and the first three feature values are discrete I can get the MMI values like so:

```
mutual_info_classif(x, y, discrete_features=[0, 1, 2])
```

Now I'd like to use the same mutual information selection in a pipeline. I'd like to do something like this

```
SelectKBest(score_func=mutual_info_classif).fit(x, y)
```

but there's no way to pass the discrete features mask to `SelectKBest`. Is there some syntax to do this that I'm overlooking, or do I have to write my own score function wrapper?

Comment: is the issue still without solutions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately I could not find this functionality for the SelectKBest. 
But what we can do easily is extend the `SelectKBest` as our custom class to override the `fit()` method which will be called.

This is the **current `fit()` method** of SelectKBest (taken from [source at github](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/feature_selection/univariate_selection.py#L324))

```
# No provision for extra parameters here
def fit(self, X, y):
    X, y = check_X_y(X, y, ['csr', 'csc'], multi_output=True)

    ....
    ....

    # Here only the X, y are passed to scoring function
    score_func_ret = self.score_func(X, y)

    ....        
    ....

    self.scores_ = np.asarray(self.scores_)

    return self
```

Now we will define our new class `SelectKBestCustom` with the changed `fit()`. I have copied everything from the above source, changing only two lines (commented about it):

```
from sklearn.utils import check_X_y

class SelectKBestCustom(SelectKBest):

    # Changed here
    def fit(self, X, y, discrete_features='auto'):
        X, y = check_X_y(X, y, ['csr', 'csc'], multi_output=True)

        if not callable(self.score_func):
            raise TypeError("The score function should be a callable, %s (%s) "
                        "was passed."
                        % (self.score_func, type(self.score_func)))

        self._check_params(X, y)

        # Changed here also
        score_func_ret = self.score_func(X, y, discrete_features)
        if isinstance(score_func_ret, (list, tuple)):
            self.scores_, self.pvalues_ = score_func_ret
            self.pvalues_ = np.asarray(self.pvalues_)
        else:
            self.scores_ = score_func_ret
            self.pvalues_ = None

        self.scores_ = np.asarray(self.scores_)
        return self
```

This can be called simply like:

```
clf = SelectKBestCustom(mutual_info_classif,k=2)
clf.fit(X, y, discrete_features=[0, 1, 2])
```

**Edit**:
The above solution can be useful in pipelines also, and the `discrete_features` parameter can be assigned different values when calling `fit()`.

**Another Solution (less preferable)**:
Still, if you just need to work `SelectKBest` with `mutual_info_classif`, temporarily (just analysing the results), we can also make a custom function which can call `mutual_info_classif` internally with hard coded `discrete_features`. Something along the lines of:

```
def mutual_info_classif_custom(X, y):
    # To change discrete_features, 
    # you need to redefine the function each time
    # Because once the func def is supplied to selectKBest, it cant be changed
    discrete_features = [0, 1, 2]

    return mutual_info_classif(X, y, discrete_features)
```

Usage of the above function:

```
selector = SelectKBest(mutual_info_classif_custom).fit(X, y)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also use partials as follows:

```py
from functools import partial

discrete_mutual_info_classif = partial(mutual_info_classif, iscrete_features=[0, 1, 2])
SelectKBest(score_func=discrete_mutual_info_classif).fit(x, y)
```